# Datatables fnDraw causes issues for other scripts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using Datatables to manage rows printed from our database. I have set rows to 5 per page but it is causing errors for my bootstrap tabs.

The JS I am using:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#feedback-table").dataTable({

     "bRetrieve": false,
      "bFilter": false,
      "iDisplayLength": 5,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "aoColumns": [
        { sWidth: '35%' },
        { sWidth: '20%' },
        { sWidth: '30%' },
        { sWidth: '15%' } ]

    });

    feedback-table.dataTable().fnDraw();

});
```

The error I get when I try to click on a bootstrap tab :

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: feedback is not defined home:281
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Error calling method on NPObject. Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
    at chrome-extension://mkfokfffehpeedafpekjeddnmnjhmcmk/docstart.js:1:2117
    at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
    at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
    at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
    at <error: illegal access>
    at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
    at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
    at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
    at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:273:22)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `dataTable` into variable and call the `fnDraw` on it

Like this:

```
var myTable = $("#feedback-table").dataTable({

 "bRetrieve": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  "iDisplayLength": 5,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  "aoColumns": [
    { sWidth: '35%' },
    { sWidth: '20%' },
    { sWidth: '30%' },
    { sWidth: '15%' } ]

});

myTable.fnDraw();
```